# MongoDB: How do I find coordinates nearby?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

In this function, I want to check if there are any posts in the database made nearby to a set of input lat/long coords so that I can display them based on where the user currently is, and I also want to write a function to check if they are in a "too close" range (less than 2m or so).

I'm not sure how to do it properly and every answer I have found online after extensive research has given me nothing. I am using NodeJS 18 LTS with the latest version of mongodb.

This is the code I tried to get the posts

```
const getPostsInRange = (lng, lat) => {

    // get all posts in range
    const postCollection = db.collection('posts')

    return postCollection.find({
        "location": {
            "$near": [parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)],
            "$maxDistance": 100000
        }})


}
```

and here is the code that calls it, from index.js

```
app.get('/getposts/:lat/:long', requiresAuth(), (req, res) => {

    const { lat, long } = req.params

    getPostsInRange(long, lat)
        .then((posts) => {

            res.send(posts)

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).end()
        })
```

what my data looks like in mongodb:

```
{
        "textBody": "new message 3",
        "image": "xxxx",
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [xxxx, xxxx]
        },
        "timestamp": 1674503437
}
```

I get errors such as
`TypeError: getPostsInRange(...).then is not a function`, and similar but slightly different ones that Google seems to have never have heard of.

i would love some help building this project, full code snippets would be greatly appreciate due to my lack of experience working with mongodb.

Comment: I believe it's not a promise (ie, `.then` isn't a function) because it's a cursor. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/find/